# The system cannot find the path specified with FileWriter

Tags: java, filewriter, file-not-found

I have this code:

```
private static void saveMetricsToCSV(String fileName, double[] metrics) {
        try {
            FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter(
                    System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\output\\" +
                    fileTimestamp + "_" + fileDBSize + "-" + fileName + ".csv"
            );

            BufferedWriter csvFile = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);

            for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    csvFile.write(String.format("%,10f;", metrics[i+j]));
                }

                csvFile.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }

            csvFile.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

But I get this error:

> C:\Users\Nazgulled\Documents\Workspace\Só
>   Amigos\output\1274715228419_5000-List-ImportDatabase.csv
>   (The system cannot find the path
>   specified)

Any idea why?

I'm using NetBeans on Windows 7 if it matters...

Comment: does that path and file exist?

Comment: also minor point, it's generally good form to use Path.Combine() ...

Comment: No, but as I'm trying to write and not read, I thought the path/file would be created automatically...

Comment: Path.Combine probably isn't a great suggestion for Java :-).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In general, a non existent file will be created by Java only if the parent directory exists.
You should check/create the directory tree:

```
  String filenameFullNoPath = fileTimestamp + "_"  + fileDBSize + "-" 
        + fileName + ".csv";
  File myFile =  new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")  + File.separator 
        + "output" + File.separator + filenameFullNoPath);
  File parentDir = myFile.getParentFile();
  if(! parentDir.exists()) 
      parentDir.mkdirs(); // create parent dir and ancestors if necessary
  // FileWriter does not allow to specify charset, better use this:
  Writer w = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(myFile),charset);
```

Comment: I think you may need to replace "myFile.getParent()" (which returns a String) with "myFile.getParentFile()".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `getParentFile` ([Java Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29)) to make sure that the parent directory exists. The following will check that the parent directory exists, and create it if it doesn't.

```
File myFile =  new File(fileName);
if(!myFile.getParentFile.exists()) {
     myFile.getParentFile.mkdirs();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd guess that the "output" directory doesn't exist.  Try adding:

```
new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "output").mkdir();
```